# Biblatex supress page prefix S. while using Citavi Publication Wizard

Tags: biblatex

I am using the `authoryear-icomp` style and I am trying to suppress the page prefix **S.** at `\autocite`s and replace them with a colon.

Yet, I am getting

> Dummy (Heinrich 2013: S. 197)

with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Heinrich.2013,
 author = {Heinrich, Michael},
 year = {2013},
 title = {Kritik der politischen {\"O}konomie: Eine Einf{\"u}hrung},
 address = {Stuttgart},
 edition = {11. Aufl.},
  publisher = {Schmetterling-Verl.},
 isbn = {3-89657-593-7},
 series = {Reihe Theorie.org}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

Dummy\autocite[S.~39]{Heinrich.2013} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Outcome]

Comment: The code should do what you want, though I would recommend `\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}`. Note that the `pages` field format is not relevant for citations like this, it is only relevant for the bibliography and `\fullcite`.

Comment: What looks a bit fishy to me is that your post seems to imply that you have this code in `biblatex.def`. `biblatex.def` is a system-installed file that should **never** be modified. Code like this can just be dropped into your preamble. Did you really edit the system file `biblatex.def` or did you create a new `biblatex.def`? Can you show us the reset of your document (ideally as a fully working and self-contained example that we can run in a new, empty folder: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/08d1c70f99fba3a62fd4e16594eee7fa works just fine for me.

Comment: Many thanks for your tips so far, @moewe!
I have come to the conclusion that the problem is somewhere else.

I use Citavi with the Publication Wizard to create intext quotes. I suspect that the S. is caused by this:

<pre>Dummy2\autocite[S.~39]{Heinrich.2013} <code>
I am left clicking on the entry in Citavi, and the \autocite[]{} appears with this entries. It seems like there is no solution to avoid **S.**.
As a "solution" would you advise to write a kind of replace command/routine to delete **S.** within the key when compiling?

Comment: Can you configure what gets inserted? Or use different software to do the insertion?

Comment: Good idea, @cfr but unfortunatly it seems like i can not customize the inserted values and nor i can use a different software. Therefor i am thinking about routine which looks for `S.~` and delete that, but I am unsure ofcourse.

Comment: I can see that might be easier, but surely you could do it differently if you wished. I just enter my reference keys by hand. If I wanted to use what you're using, I'd probably just write a script to clean up the source at the end before final compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question nicely illustrates why it is recommended to give the postnote/page reference in the optional argument to `\cite`-like commands without the page prefix: `biblatex` can automatically insert the correct prefix if needed, but if the prefix is already given it is *much* harder to remove it if it is not desired.

`biblatex` has no function to strip the `S.~`  from the postnote and this should definitely be fixed on the exporter side: Citavi shouldn't insert `S.~` if it generates citations for `biblatex`.

Here is a workaround using LaTeX3 and its regex functions to strip the `S.~` automatically. **This is only a last resort, the input should be fixed instead.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \mknormrangeWithoutS:n #1
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_postnote_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {\AS\.\~} {} \l_postnote_tl
  \exp_args:No \mknormrange \l_postnote_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mknormrangeWithoutS}{m}{
  \mknormrangeWithoutS:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrangeWithoutS{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrangeWithoutS{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Dummy \autocite[S.~39]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Dummy (Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998: 39)]

Comment: thanks a lot - it works perfectly!  I will still trying to get Citavi inserting the data without the Prefix `S.`. If I could solve this, I'd post it here. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same issue: The citavi support has informed me that the prefix `S.~` is hardcoded and it is unable to deactivate. Therefor, @moewe's script is the needed and perfectly working work around.